# How to hide and send keystrokes to a command prompt window using perl?

Tags: windows, perl, background

I have written a perl script using Win32::GUItest to send keystrokes to a command prompt window in windows, now when my script runs, it uses the system function in perl and opens a new cmd.exe file and keystrokes are sent to it. everything work fine till here but i dont want that command prompt window to be visible and users manually running the script. I want the keystrokes to be sent into the cmd.exe window in the background. i want to schedule the script using schtasks using windows 64 bit server.

Please do not suggest me to use `Proc::Background`, `Win32::Service` and `Win32::Daemon` unless you have really tried this task working fine for you using them.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I don't have permissions to ssh to a linux server from which i need to collect logs. I have a tool installed on windows server which has cli.exe where i can execute the commands using keystrokes from perl win32::guitest and collect the audit log reports where it works fine and saves the output file in a location. this is done manaully but i want to automate it by scheduling it as schtasks on windows server where the tool is installed. keystrokes are being sent only when the cli.exe is active . I want it to send the keystrokes to the cli.exe window in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could control the console with [`Win32::Console`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Console-0.09/Console.pm).

I don't have experience with it but docs sound promising: since there's a `Display()` function, I assume that the console is hidden by default.

Comment: I have installed Win32::Console on my windows machine and giving a try with the commands in cpan.org. could you please provide any link with examples using win32::console.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send a [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WM_UNICHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the window in question, instead of relying on the window being active and in the foreground.

This example seems to work for me. I was able to switch to other applications while keys were being sent to `links` running in a `cmd.exe` window. By the time I was done typing an email, links had navigated to `example.com`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Encode qw(encode);
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );
use Win32::GuiTest qw(SendMessage ShowWindow WaitWindow);

use constant WM_CHAR => 0x0102;
use constant SW_HIDE => 0;
use constant SW_SHOW => 5;

system qw(start links);

my $hwnd = WaitWindow('Links', 5);

ShowWindow $hwnd, SW_HIDE;

send_message($hwnd, "ghttp://example.com/\r");

ShowWindow $hwnd, SW_SHOW;

send_message($hwnd, "q\r", 3_000_000);

sub send_message {
    my ($hwnd, $msg, $delay) = @_;

    $delay ||= 25_000;
    my @keys = encode_keys($msg);

    for my $key (@keys) {
        SendMessage $hwnd, WM_CHAR, $key, 0;
        usleep $delay;
    }
    return;
}

sub encode_keys {
    my ($msg) = @_;
    map ord, map encode('UTF16-LE', $_), split //, $msg;
}
```

Comment: I tried running the above code as it is, it throws me an error "windows could not find links".

Comment: Many Thanks in advance. I replaced links with cmd.exe to the script and it is working fine for me now, however i noticed the cmd.exe window popping up and then hiding. what should i do to hide the cmd.exe completely until my script sends the last command, also how to kill the window after all the commands are completed, also how to send messages to this window when a new cmd.exe window is opened by some other user logged in at the time of script run making it unique.

Comment: Obviously, you can start the `cmd` window minimized, and then hide it. There is a different way one can do this, but it is somewhat involved. I already [blogged about the first step](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/07/on-windows-how-can-i-find-window.html), but the rest of it will have to wait until after I get done with other projects.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, in the mean time i will try to figure out the solution

Comment: Hi Sinan, i am trying to schedule the script run using schtasks on windows, when i run the script from command prompt as "perl script.pl" it is working fine but when i schedule it, it is not working. schtasks /create /tn "name" /tr "D:\Audit\collectAuditLogs.pl" /sc daily /st 13:00 /ru admin   I created this admin account and added it to the adminsitrators group which has equal privileges. could you please try to schedule the task on your machine and see what the problem is please

Comment: No, I do not have time for that. But, at a first glance, I would ask myself, if there really would be a window to send messages to when I have schedule task that is run non-interactively. Anyway, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/22/712677.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, but when i run the task using schtasks i can see in the task manager, the cli.exe opening multiple times but when i run it with my username logging into the server it works fine but with the admin account it fails creating the output files. it opens multiple cli.exe windows processes. i can see the schtasks /query output where the task type is set as interactive/background.

Comment: I found the answer by myself, all we need to do is, just create a local admin user on the server and add him to the logon as batch job under Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\Local security policy\Local Policies\user rights assignment\Logon as batch job\Add user. now use schtasks to schedule the tasks with proper paramteres.